# Log events of android application via facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

I have been really bugged up as in how to log in my android events via facebook sdk.......has the facebook provided with any provision in its sdk, if its there, does any one of you have got the idea how to implement it?

Any sort of help shall save a submerging ship.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this link. It shows the method you need to call through your Facebook SDK to get Logging information for requests and staff!

[Facebook Logging Behaviour](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/LoggingBehavior)

Comment: I suppose you misunderstood my question :
I simply meant how can we trap the events via facebooK Sdk.....which classes do i need to look into in order to do so ?
Like we do with flurry and Google analytics or any other 3rd party Api....such as Apps Flyer.....

Comment: Oh yeah i totally got it wrong! Well i have only tried my way with BugSense so i think if you enable this behaviour and you modify it to send the data to your 3rd party SDK it will be fine!